# Add WiFi network via ACTION_WIFI_ADD_NETWORKS intent

Tags: android, wifi

I am trying to connect to a WiFi network using the new [Wifi suggest API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-suggest). Specifically I want to add the network to the list, so as the documentation says I have to implement [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings?hl=en#ACTION_WIFI_ADD_NETWORKS) intent.

This is what I have right now:

```
val suggestion = if (wifiConnection.authentication == AUTHENTICATION_NOPASS) {
    WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
            .setSsid(wifiConnection.ssid)
            .build()
} else {
    WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
            .setSsid(wifiConnection.ssid)
            .setWpa2Passphrase(wifiConnection.password)
            .build()
}

val intent = Intent(ACTION_WIFI_ADD_NETWORKS)
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_WIFI_NETWORK_LIST, arrayListOf(suggestion))
startActivityForResult(intent, 1002)
```

However when I run this code I get the following crash:

> 2020-10-12 16:38:48.291 17001-17001/com.my.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
> EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.my.app PID: 17001
> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.WIFI_ADD_NETWORKS }
> at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2076)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1720)
> at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5258)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
> at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5203)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
> at com.my.app.presentation.ui.activity.ConnectActivity.connectApi29(ConnectActivity.kt:504)
> at com.my.app.presentation.ui.activity.ConnectActivity.connect(ConnectActivity.kt:343)
> at com.my.app.presentation.ui.activity.ConnectActivity.access$connect(ConnectActivity.kt:70)
> at com.my.app.presentation.ui.activity.ConnectActivity$setReadyState$1.onClick(ConnectActivity.kt:334)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7862)
> at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:15004)
> at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7831)
> at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:879)

What is the correct way of opening the WiFi list to enable the user to chose the suggested network for addition?

Comment: Where is the context here `Intent(ACTION_WIFI_ADD_NETWORKS)` ?

Comment: What version of Android are you using? [That `Intent` action](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/provider/Settings#action_wifi_add_networks) is for Android 11 and higher.

Comment: I'm using Android 10, API 29; but I am targeting API 30, shouldn't I be able to use it anyway?

Comment: This does not work in Android 11, Oneplus device too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This intent action is added in API Level 30 so if you are running this code on the device running on API Level 29 or below, it won't work.
Please make sure the device or emulator is running on API Level 30.

Comment: So how can we achieve the same thing on android api 29?

Comment: @OmarRedani You can use WifiSuggestions API on API 29 and use method wifiManager.addNetworkSuggestions(suggestionsList) to add networks. Link - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-suggest